# Django defaulting to HTTPS

Tags: python, django, django-sslify

I have a working django install with django-sslify and it correctly HTTPS my urls but with inconsistent behaviour.

For example, if I type socialspark.spuro.org it takes me to an HTTP page.
If I type socialspark.spuro.org/something it takes me to an HTTPS page.

Of course, if I type https://socialspark.spuro.org/ it will take me to an HTTPS page.

It's concerning for me that with one misspelling, all my HTTPS support will be gone. What should I do to remedy this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [django-secure](https://github.com/carljm/django-secure), it's got middleware that can do this for you. After you installed it you can put this in your settings.py:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

However if you have the access, you could also do this in the webserver (Nginx, Apache). That will be much faster.

Comment: Wicked! I'm going to give this a go and if I'm all set will give you the answer. Thank you for your help.